# Memory Leaks when Working with Address Book Contacts in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, ios6

I'm using ARC, and my application compiles and works without crashing. However, when I run an Analyze build, I am seeing these warnings. I come from PHP and JavaScript so naturally I have no idea what to do to fix this stuff. Can anyone help me out?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ARC needs some help when dealing with Core Foundation. Try this:

```
NSArray *linkedPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople(person);
```

and

```
NSDictionary *personDictionary = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addressFromPerson, 0));
```

`__bridge_transfer` tells ARC that a non-Objective-C (i.e., Core Foundation) pointer is being moved to an Objective-C pointer, and it allows ARC to take ownership of the object for memory management purposes. CF functions with the word "copy" in them produce an object reference with a +1 reference count. If you don't explicitly call `CFRelease()` on the object later, then it will leak. Using `__bridge_transfer`, however, lets ARC do this for you.

(Note: I didn't test this, but I believe those are the issues that the static analyzer is complaining about.)

Comment: Keep in mind, however, that the `__bridge_transfer` is only to be used when casting from a C pointer to an object pointer. One of his static analyzer issues involves an `ABMultiValueRef`, which can technically be cast to an Objective-C object of type `ABMultiValue` and used with `__bridge_transfer`, but he's not leveraging that cast here.

Comment: Used a combo of both recommendations, no more warnings on analyzing! Thank you both!

Comment: While it's the same thing, Apple now recommends `CFBridgingRelease()`.

Comment: @Rob Where did you see this recommendation?

Comment: @LucasTizma See my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13656456/1271826). In short, WWDC 2012 "Modern Objective-C", 37:33 into the presentation.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use:

```
NSArray *linkedPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople(person);
```

But Apple now recommends using:

```
NSArray *linkedPeople = CFBridgingRelease(ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople(person));
```

It does the same thing, but Apple recommends you use the latter.

See [WWDC 2012 session 405](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=405), 37:33 into the presentation.

Answer (score 1):

So! Even though you're using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), it's still a good idea to read up on Objective-C Memory Management:

http://longweekendmobile.com/2011/09/07/objc-automatic-reference-counting-in-xcode-explained/

But, for your specific problem:

Generally, when you see a C method in the Apple frameworks that has the word `Copy` in it, you're taking ownership of that Core Foundation type and you need to release it. When you want to release that type, just use:

```
CFRelease(addressFromPerson)
```

That's the first issue. Your screenshot **cuts off the second error** so I'm only speculating, but I think you also need to release your `NSDictionary *personDictionary`. Similarly:

```
CFRelease(personDictionary)
```

*Note that you also need to manage the memory for `linkedPeople`*

Normally ARC will take care of memory management for you, but when working with Core Foundation types, you still need to clean up after yourself.

I would **strongly** recommend you check out these great resources on memory management with ARC, particularly when dealing with CF types and toll-free bridging:

http://www.joergjacobsen.com/blog/2011/10/05/managing-toll-free-bridging-in-an-arced-environment/

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I used Lucas's bridge_transfer as well as your recommendation CFRelease(addressFromPerson);. Wish I could mark both answers as accepted, since each helped. =] Instead, have an upvote!

Comment: @Kirk Cool beans, happy coding!